# How to parse xhtml file using jsoup

Tags: xhtml, jsoup

I am using Jsoup for parsing my pages but its seems Jsoup is only parsing HTML files. Is there any way to parse XHTML files in Jsoup? Is there any XHTML to HTML converter?
I am loading my files using URL. Below is the code:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc =org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse("http://localhost:7001/sample.xhtml");
String title=doc.title();
System.out.println(title);
```

In above code title comes as blank because its not able to understand the XHTML file.

Comment: So, that URL didn't invoke FacesServlet, the one responsible for converting XHTML to HTML? Perhaps you forgot to map FacesServlet on *.xhtml URL pattern? What exactly are you trying to do? Do you actually understand what XHTML is and how JSF uses it to generate HTML output?

Comment: Yes balus in Jsf we can't do that I am thinking for jsoup is there any jsoup feature which provides direct parsing

Comment: If I wanted to do in Jsf I need to get html source by fetching the uicomponent by using facescontext

Comment: Here I wanted to do html sanitization by using jsoup

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anymore what to say. There are too much fundamental misunderstandings in the complete picture. I suggest to take a pause and learn web development and security from scratch.

Comment: @BalusC I always admire your suggestion. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong method. The [`parse`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.lang.String-) method is used to load some HTML string. Here it receives an url. This is why you get an empty title.

Instead use the code below that use the [`connect`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#connect-java.lang.String-) method:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect("http://localhost:7001/sample.xhtml").get();
String title=doc.title();
System.out.println(title);
```

Comment: Thanks I was using wrong method. I am able to fetch the document.